# How to make double navbar responsive

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, navbar

I am currently redesigning a website who has a two row responsive navbar , but now get stuck.

```css
@media (min-width: 767px) {
.nav.navbar-nav {
 float: right;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse ">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li class="community"><a href="#"><strong>Community</strong></a></li>
<li class="global"><a href="#"><strong>Global</strong></a></li>

</ul>
</div>

<div class="navbar-header">

<div id="button" type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
<span class="icon-bar"></span> 
<span class="icon-bar"></span> 
<span class="icon-bar"></span> 
<span class="icon-bar"></span> 
<span class="icon-bar"></span> 
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
</div>

<a class="brand" href="#"><img src="IMAGE/Oppo_green.png" height="24" width="150" alt=""></a>
</div>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">

<li><a href="#"><strong>Home</strong></a></li>

<li class="dropdown">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><strong>Products</strong></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li>Smartphones</li>
<li>Accessoires</li>
</ul>
</li>

<li><a href="a"><strong>ColorOS</strong></a></li> 

<li class="dropdown">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><strong>About</strong></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li>Press</li>
</ul>
</li>

<li class="dropdown">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><strong>Support</strong></a> 
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li>FAQ</li>
<li>Contact</li>
</ul>
</li>

<li><a href="#"><strong>Stores</strong></a></li>

</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

[image][image]

If the screen is wider than 767px it looks like this (which looks precisely what I want (check first image)...but..
when the screen is smaller than 767px (second image), the navigation menu looks like this and that is not what I want. "Community" and "global" should be displayed below under store, but how can I fix that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just add duplicate menu options, meaning hide the first one on tablet/phone and show the second one on tablet/phone, as so: (check bottom of second navigation for adjustment)

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <!-- hide this nav on tablet/phone ****************************** -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse hidden-sm hidden-xs">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="community"><a href="#"><strong>Community</strong></a></li>
            <li class="global"><a href="#"><strong>Global</strong></a></li>    
        </ul>
    </div>    
    <div class="navbar-header">    
        <div id="button" type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </div>    
        <a class="brand" href="#"><img src="IMAGE/Oppo_green.png" height="24" width="150" alt=""></a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">    
            <li><a href="#"><strong>Home</strong></a></li>    
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><strong>Products</strong></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li>Smartphones</li>
                    <li>Accessoires</li>
                </ul>
            </li>    
            <li><a href="a"><strong>ColorOS</strong></a></li>    
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><strong>About</strong></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li>Press</li>
                </ul>
            </li>    
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><strong>Support</strong></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li>FAQ</li>
                    <li>Contact</li>
                </ul>
            </li>    
            <li><a href="#"><strong>Stores</strong></a></li>  

            <!-- ****************************************************** -->
            <li class="visible-sm visible-xs">
                <!-- link here (or dropdown) for "Community" -->
            </li> 
            <li class="visible-sm visible-xs">
                <!-- link here (or dropdown) for "Global" -->
            </li> 
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I find that whenever you have custom CSS for certain elements, and they're on the page a certain way (either inside other containers, etc), then it's easier to use this approach rather than manipulate w/ JS and/or adjust a whole bunch of CSS